# python rolling cumulative return with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and would like to get the rolling cumulative return over the last lets say for this example 2 periods grouped by an identifier. For my actual case I need a longer period, but my problem is more with the groupby:

```
        id        return
2012     1           0.5 
2012     2           0.2 
2013     1           0.1 
2013     2           0.3
```

The result should look like this:

```
        id        return        cumreturn
2012     1           0.5         0.5
2012     2           0.2         0.2
2013     1           0.1         0.65
2013     2           0.3         0.56
```

It is import that the period is rolling. I have the following formula so far:

```
df["cumreturn"] = df.groupby("id")["return"].fillna(0).pd.rolling_apply(df,5,lambda x: np.prod(1+x)-1)
```

However, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'pd'. I know how to get the rolling cumulative return. However, I just cant figure out how to combine it with groupby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df_out = (df.set_index('id', append=True)
            .assign(cumreturn=df.groupby('id')['return'].rolling(2,min_periods=1)
                                .apply(lambda x: np.prod(1+x)-1)
            .swaplevel(0,1)).reset_index(1))
```

Output:

```
      id  return  cumreturn
2012   1     0.5       0.50
2012   2     0.2       0.20
2013   1     0.1       0.65
2013   2     0.3       0.56
```

Comment: Sorry, Meetings,   (-:

Comment: @piRSquared.... I learn from your submissions; that is why I am asking.  Happy Meeting!